# Relevant sling:resourceType for xtype:htmleditor

Tags: content-management-system, adobe, aem

As we know that for:

**xtype**:textfield-->**resouceType**:granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textfield

**xtype**:textarea-->**resouceType** :granite/ui/components/foundation/form/textarea.

I want this:

xtype:htmleditor-->**resouceType**:?

I have created one custom component with **xtype: htmleditor** so, that I can achieve font face like "Arial", "tahoma" etc and font size as well.

The above xtype is for classic UI. But, when I was trying to create cq:dialog for touch UI using dialog converter tool I couldn't get relevant sling:resourceType for "htmleditor ".

Don't we have relevant sling:resourceType for xtype:htmleditor ? Please confirm.

[dialog properties tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAyTD.png)